# Admin menu bar covers part of the screen while working in mobile mode

Tags: theming

I think that the image I attached says it all - a part of the screen is covered by admin menu in mobile view from my pc (this is the default firefox mobile view).

It's extremely problematic when I need to check something that is at the fold of the page, i.e at the top part of the page beacuse it also being covered and I have no where to scroll-up to, and must logout to view it or check through another browser and this can be tiresome sometimes.

[image]

Comment: If I'm not wrong your requirement is to hide the `admin_menu` only on the mobile view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no configuration settings at `admin/config/administration/admin_menu` for hiding the `admin_menu` at the mobile screen, hence you can do 2 things:

1. Either inspect you site in `incognito` mode of Chrome or `private browsing` in Firefox
2. Permanent solution would be applying `CSS` for this

   `@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
     #admin-menu {
       display: none;
     }
   }`

Answer (score 2):

You could also choose to change your backend to a responsive backend. I had good results with the [adminimal theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/adminimal_theme) and it's companion [adminimal admin menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/adminimal_admin_menu) module. This resulted in a slick responsive backend on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a [Media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to your CSS that hides the menu < a certain width.

Or, you could just pop open a new private window in FF which would get around having to log out.